# Confused about the following integral given a joint density function...

Tags: probability, integration, expectation

> Let $X,Y$ be random variables with joint pdf
>   $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{8}\cdot e^{-y}\cdot(y^2-x^2)\cdot I_{\{\;|x|\;\leq \;y\;, \;y>0\}}$$
>   Find $E[X]$.

I found that the marginal density of $X$ is 
$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{4}e^{-|x|}(1+|x|)\cdot I_{\{x\;\in\;\mathbb{R}\}}$$
$$=\begin{cases} 
     \frac{1}{4}e^{-x}(1+x)  & x\geq 0 \\
      \frac{1}{4}e^{x}(1-x) & x< 0 \\ 
   \end{cases} $$
Assuming I've defined my domain correctly, we should then have that
$$E[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} xf(x)dx$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R^-}} \frac{1}{4}e^{x}\cdot x(1-x)$$
$$E[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} xf(x)dx$$
$$= \int_{\mathbb{R^\textbf{_}}} \frac{1}{4}e^{x}\cdot x(1-x)dx +\int_{\mathbb{R^\textbf{+}}}\frac{1}{4}e^{-x}(1+x)dx = 1$$
$$\implies E[X]=1$$

But apparently the answer is $0$ (maybe the textbook is wrong?). Did I represent my piecewise function incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text book is correct. The marginal density of $X$ is indeed
$$
f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y)dy=\begin{cases} 
     \frac{1}{4}e^{-x}(1+x)  & x\geq 0 \\
      \frac{1}{4}e^{x}(1-x) & x< 0, \\ 
   \end{cases}
$$ giving

> $$
> \begin{align}
> E(X)&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\times f_X(x)dx
> \\\\&=\int_{-\infty}^0x\times \frac{1}{4}e^{x}(1-x)dx+\int_0^{+\infty}x\times \frac{1}{4}e^{-x}(1+x)dx
> \\\\&=-\frac34+\frac34
> \\\\&=0.
> \end{align}
> $$

Apparently, your mistake comes from your computation of $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R^-}} \frac{1}{4}e^{x}\cdot x(1-x)dx$.

Comment: Yup I see what  I was doing wrong now. Because I was used to integrating $x^n e^{-x}$, I wasn't alternating the signs when doing integration by parts in my head. Thank you!